# How to pass AJAX data to child through props

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to create two tables, where I can pull data into a parent component, pass data into one table, and allow for moving data from one table to another. So I need to be able to have one table for all AJAX data, then one for Selected data. I am unable to pass data in through props, as once the AJAX request is complete, the child does not update. (Basically parent component observes and shares the data between the two children.)

I have tried the "WillReceive" and "WillUpdate" style methods in the documentation, but they are never called, I tried updating state

here is the request (I am faking the data for now)

```
getInvoiceData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("hi");
        resolve([{number: "1"},{number: "2"},{number: "3"}]);
    })

}
```

heres where I use the req

```
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    self.getInvoiceData()
        .then((response) => {
            self.state.invoices = response;
            console.log(self.state);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        })
}
```

heres my render

```
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Selected:
                {
                    function() {return JSON.parse(this.selected)}
                }
            </p>
            <InvoicePickTable invoices = {this.state.invoices} selected = {this.selected} />
            <button>Move</button>
            <InvoiceSelectedTable selectedInvoices = {this.state.selectedInvoices} />
        </div>

    );
}
```

heres my child

```
import React from 'react';

class InvoicePickTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        console.log("constructor called");
        super(props);
        this.state = {invoices: []};
    }
    selectInvoice(invoice) {
        this.props.selected = invoice;
    }

    //never gets called
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log(nextProps);
        console.log(nextState)
        console.log("eyy lmao");
        this.state.invoices = nextProps.invoices;
        this.state.hasDate = true;
    }
    //never gets called
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log(nextProps);
        console.log("eyy lrofl");
        this.state.invoices = nextProps.invoices;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Invoice #</th>
                        <th>Task Price</th>
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th>Task Name</th>
                        <th><button onClick={()=>{console.log(this.props);console.log(this.state)}}>props</button></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {

                    this.props.invoices.map(function (invoice) {
                        console.log("in");
                        console.log(invoice);
                        return (
                            <tr key = {invoice.number} onClick={this.selectInvoice(invoice)}>
                                <td>{invoice.number}</td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }

}

export default InvoicePickTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for updating state you must use `setState()` function , please try this :

```
 componentDidMount() {
        const self = this;
        self.getInvoiceData()
            .then((response) => {


                this.setState({
                    invoices : response
                 });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick was not to manipulate state in the parent directly, but instead to use the setState({}) function.